# Select a complet Tag using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to select a group div for example:

```
<div><span>stackoverflow</span></div>
```

how can i do to out all this in a variable `tmp`, and the output of `tmp`, should be something like : `console.log(tmp) // <div><span>stackoverflow</span></div>`

how i can do tht with Jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the below:

```
<div><span>stackoverflow</span></div>
```

JS:

```
var tmp = $("div")[0]; 
//Or tmp = $("div").get(0);
console.log ( tmp );
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var tmp = $('div > span').parent(); // 拿到div内部是span的所有div <br><br>
console.log(tmp); // 打印输出
```

Comment: console.log(tmp.html());

Comment: Some explanation (in English) would be nice. Also you should edit your answer to correct it instead of adding a comment.